# How to change a button data-icon size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change data-icon size in jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 - for example:

```
<a href="#workerPageForDetails" id="findAJobButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="search">Find a job</a>
```

I want the search icon to fill all the button if possible, resize it if not.

Can CSS or jQuery do that?  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the background scale of the icon: `background-size: 75%;`

Comment: add that to the css or the html tag?

Comment: on the icon ex: #findAJobButton{background-size: 75%;}

Answer (score 2):

32 x 32 pixel icons using CSS:

```
.ui-btn::after {
    background-size: 32px !important;
    width: 32px !important;
    height: 32px !important;
}
```

Comment: Little bit late, but you maybe have to adjust margin-left, too if you use icon position bottom or top.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the icon with your own custom icon and make it whatever size you want.

```
.ui-icon-search {
    background-image: url('search.png');
    width:24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```